# Angular-js ng-readonly when condition is false

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to `<inpute type="text" ng-readnly="!someVariable"`.

When I breakpoint,  `$scope.someVariable` is true, but the input field is read-only.

Can I not use a `!` ?

How can I code this?

---

[Update] If not,I imagine that I can `ng-change` the field and ignore the change if the condition is false.

Comment: Can you pls add some more code ?

Comment: Not without posting the whole app ;-)  When I breakpoint, `$scope.someVariable` is true, but the input field is read-only. Can you tell me what more I can post? I **do** appreciate your help (+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with your logic, it's with the code.

Look at your syntax :

```
<inpute type="text" ng-readnly="!someVariable"
```

Spelling issue `inpute`, `ng-readnly` and missing closing tag.

Change it to this,

```
<input type="text" ng-readonly="!someVariable">
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/IYsghD8pdJ2DmCvzutuN?p=preview)

Comment: My bad, I typed the code in, rather than copy/paste. Those typos are not in my code. uUt I award the answer because you have proved what I was sure was correct - there is no problem in negating the condition. I will recode with an `ng-change`, to allow me to debug my problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Pls see the following example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-readonly="play">
<button ng-click="toggle()">Toggle It</button>
<script>
//App declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
//Controller Declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.play = true;
    $scope.toggle = function(){
        $scope.play= !$scope.play;
    }
});

</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Hope, it helps!

As per your requirements, just change the required line to this:

```
<input type="text" ng-readonly="!play">
```

Comment: Sorry if I miss the point, but that looks like a straightforward `ng-readonly` - my question is whether I can negate the condition with a preceding `!`

Comment: Yes you can. It will simple reverse the condition for readonly.

Comment: Hmmm wonder why it isn't working for me. Thanks for saying that it should (I presume that you have tested your code. I will figure it out & get back to you.